# My 'c' code prints weird stuff after printing the required output

Tags: c

My code is about saying one sentence about Berlin .. Part of this sentence starts with "Berlin " and the other part is from standard input from the user .. after printing the output .. I get weird random things like "w$

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){

    #define MAX 1000

    char arr [MAX] ;
    char star [] = "Berlin ";
    int i = 0;

    while ((arr[i] = getchar()) != '\n') {
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s%s", star,arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you an example of what you tried ?

Comment: `arr` isn't null terminated. insert `arr[i] = `\0`;` just before the printf

Comment: Yes you are right .. It's working appropriately now .. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included the null terminator for `arr` (since you are printing it as a C-string using `%s`).

Add

```
arr[i] = 0;
```

after the while loop.

There are two other potential problems:

1. You haven't done bounds check. So `arr` could overflow if you enter more than 1000 chars.
2. `getchar()` can return `EOF` on input failure which you need to take into account.

Comment: Yes you are right .. It's working appropriately now .. Thanks alot :)